# Query Multiple Post types each with own meta query

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query

I have 2 post types: lets say `products` and `product_variations`. I'd like to be able to modify the query via `pre_get_posts` to get all product with meta_keys `"_visible" = "true"` and `"_available" = "true"` AND all product_variations with meta_key `"_featured" = "true"`.

The product_variations don't have the meta_keys `"_visible"/"_available"` and vice versa, so a straight up `AND` meta_query returns no results. `OR` relation isn't quite right either as two fields are `AND` related for one post type then `OR` related to the other post type.

To make that slightly more visual because I just realized how complex it is to write out:

```
**product**        
_visible = true      
_available = true

**product_variation**      
_featured = true
```

Is this possible via query args?
Is this possible via `posts_where`?
Do I need to run a separate query and then somehow merge the results?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is beyond simple query arguments. I have written several answers about [merging queries](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+merge+query) and [a lot about `posts_where`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+posts_where). One of the two should do it. I love a good `WP_Query` question, but don't have time to write an answer. Do you have the exact SQL you need to query to generate?

Comment: Thank you both for the great comments. I have some more research to do obviously. I don't have anything exact at this point was just kind of mulling it around in my head.

Comment: I created the experimental [*Combined Query*](https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries) plugin on GitHub some time ago when I was playing with dynamic UNION queries generation. Maybe that can help in this case?

Comment: @birgire if you have time, it would be nice seeing this as an answer with some code and explanation. Most people don't read comments, and I really do feel that even though this is a plugin, it can be really useful answer as we get many questions combining queries.

Comment: Sure if it makes sense as a solution for OP ;-) I just updated it so it can be easily used for main queries as well as secondary queries. ps: there are 5-6 examples on the GitHub page that I could try to adopt to similar cases as here. I also plan to test it further when I get some extra time ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: @birgire i did see the updates and examples, looks promosing. That is why I recommended an answer if you have time. I think it will make sense to many ;-)

Comment: Well *I* read the comments! I didn't expect to get so many really great responses to this. I'm busy getting ready to move  across the Atlantic, but I will try to test these out tomorrow.

Comment: @helgatheviking good luck and strongs with the move :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach with `pre_get_posts`.

- Use `get_posts()` ( x2 queries ) to get **all** the post ids of each post type according to its requirements. Add the `fields` parameter (`'fields' => 'ids'`) to your query arguments to just fetch post ids as this is what we need, nothing else. This will drastically improve performance and will not be that tough on resources. So, you will end up with two arrays of post ids
- You now need to merge the two arrays with `array_merge()` to create a "super" array which will hold all the post ids
- You would want to look into saving this in a transient and flushing the transient when a post is updated, trashed, untrashed or published. This will ensure that do not comprise performance of your site.
- Now that you have an array of ID's fitting your needs, you can just pass that array of post ids to `post__in` in `pre_get_posts`

Example (*and untested as this is only an illustration. Unfortunately I don't have time for proper coding*)

```
function get_all_special_posts()
{
     /*
     * This is here were you would want to introduce your transient
     */
    $args1 = [
        'post_type' => 'post_type_1',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'meta_query' => [[ /*Your specific custom fields */ ]]
    ];
    $query1 = get_posts( $args1 );

    $args2 = [
        'post_type' => 'post_type_2',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'meta_query' => [[ /*Your specific custom fields */ ]]
    ];
    $query2 = get_posts( $args2 );

    $post_ids = array_merge( $query1, $query2 );

    /*
     * Set your transient here, you would want to store $post_ids in the transient
     */

    return $post_ids;
}
```

Remember to create a function to flush your transient on post publish, trash, untrash and update. Look at `transition_post_status` for this. Very versatile hook. Use `$post->post_type` to target your two desired post types only

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_home() ) {
        $q->set( 'post__in', get_all_special_posts() );
    }
});
```

Just to note, I would first check whether `get_all_special_posts()` actually have a valid array and that it is not empty before passing it to `post__in`

Answer (score 4):

> Is this possible via query args?

I don't think so.

> Is this possible via `'posts_where'`?

It is probably doable using *some* `'posts_*'` filters, not only with `'posts_where'`. Or maybe using [`'posts_request'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_request/) filter to completely oveeride the query.

> Do I need to run a separate query and then somehow merge the results?

That would be the simplest choice, the most easy to customize e.g would be easy to use a limit for products and a different limit for product variations.

Moreover, this approach is not necessarily the worst on performance side, because not always 2 queries are slower than a single one if the latter is very complex.

The 4th alternative would be build a completely custom SQL. A (vaguely tested) query that might do the trick is the following:

```
$products_and_variations = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT products.* FROM {$wpdb->posts} products
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} meta1 ON meta1.post_id = products.ID
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} meta2 ON meta2.post_id = products.ID
      WHERE products.post_type = 'product'
      AND products.post_status = 'publish'
      AND (meta1.meta_key = '_visible' AND meta1.meta_value = '1')
      AND (meta2.meta_key = '_available' AND meta2.meta_value = '1')
      GROUP BY products.ID

    UNION

    SELECT variations.* FROM {$wpdb->posts} variations
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} meta3 ON meta3.post_id = variations.ID
      WHERE variations.post_type = 'product_variation'
      AND variations.post_status = 'publish'
      AND (meta3.meta_key = '_featured' AND meta3.meta_value = '1')
      GROUP BY variations.ID
  )
  posts
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT 0, 100
");
```

You can notice:

- how complex it is
- how is not possible to use a limit for products and a different limit for variations: it is only possible to limit the *merged* results.

Before to use something like that, I would test its performance comparing them with the 2-queries approach and only use the custom query if there is any appreciable performance improvement.